# ng-model changes of type in radio button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, radio-button

Please note this example:

[JSFiddle Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/LdtM9/1/)

```
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    var ng-model = {{myValue}} - {{myType}}

       <input type="radio" value="true" 
    name="boolean" ng-change="logIt()" ng-model="myValue" /> True
        <input type="radio" value="false" 
    name="boolean" ng-change="logIt()" ng-model="myValue" /> False

    </div>
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

    function myCtrl($scope)
    {    
        $scope.myValue = true; //does not work
        //$scope.myValue = 'true'; //it does work
        $scope.myType =(typeof $scope.myValue);    
        $scope.logIt=function(){
            $scope.myType =(typeof $scope.myValue);
        }
    }
```

As you can see initially typeof is of type boolean but after selecting a value it changes to string, and true is not equal to 'true'. Is there any way I can make angular preserve the original type.

At this point I am considering to write my own directive to control this behavior but it does not look right that angular changes the original type, am I correct?.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `ng-value` and angular will handle converting back to boolean:

Here is the [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z9t7e/).

And obligatory code:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <h1>Sample 1- Booleans</h1>

var ng-model = {{myValue}} - {{myType}}
    <br />
    <input type="radio" ng-value="true" name="boolean" ng-change="logIt()" ng-model="myValue" /> True
    <input type="radio" ng-value="false" name="boolean" ng-change="logIt()" ng-model="myValue" /> False 
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting I checked the documentation for the radio button and did not find the ng-value http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.8/docs/api/ng.directive:input.radio.
Thanks for the quick reply.